# How to push into array of nested object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongo doc with an object that holds two arrays of id's

```
Musics {
_id: ""evsdfbsfb"
name: "muh jams"
playlists: {
 type1: ["dfngdfgnd", "dfgdfgn"]
 type2: ['dfgndfndgn','dndgndgndgnd"]
 }
}
```

I've tried pushing an id like so

```
let music = await MusicModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id:input.music}, { playlists: { "$push": { "type1" : type1._id }}}, {new: true})
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.dot` notation with playlist object

```
await MusicModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "_id":  input.music },
  { "playlists.type1": { "$push": type1._id }},
  { "new": true }
)
```